# How to get Visual Studio O/R Designer to auto generate collection of inherited objects?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, dbml

I have a project for which I am making use of the O/R designer in visual studio.

I would like to log history against multiple record types using the same basic table.

To do this, I have a "History" table which takes an int named "Type" and an int named "ObjectId".

Normally when creating an association in the dbml O/R designer, visual studio will auto generate the property that returns a collection of the name of the child of any onetomany association. (Example: record.histories => IEnumerable).

In this instance, I have created a table in the dbml called "RecordHistory", and this inherits from base class History. The inheritance default is History, base class discriminator value is 0, derived class discriminator value is 1 and the discriminator property is "Type".

My issue is that I do not have available to me the collection "RecordHistories", which is the name of the child property of the onetomany association I created between "Record" and "RecordHistory". I tried recreating these associations and inheritances in a different order, done cleans and rebuilds, turned off and on again etc and still don't have this collection generated for me.

Any help would be fantastic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've now solved this. The Id values for the tables were not set up as primary keys (also with automatic enumeration) in the database.

I feel a fool, but I hope this answer might help others with a similar picnic (problem in chair not in computer) problem!